# Combining and Randomizing Columns with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column of data I need to replicate X times side by side, randomized. The randomization is for a survey to be fielded where the list is jumbled for unbiased selection and doing it by hand would take quite a long time.

I am newer to SQL so please bear with me. With my limited knowledge, here's how I would think the query should work.

```
SELECT MAKEMODEL, (SELECT MAKEMODEL FROM BWMM ORDER BY NEWID())
FROM BWMM
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Essentially this would give me something like this

```
A E 
B D 
C B 
D A
E C
```

You get the idea. I appreciate any feedback or direction you can give me.

PS: Conceptually, its a lot like this post regarding a VBA solution to a similar question [Randomize Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651553/randomize-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  set_a
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rand_id, * FROM BWWM
)
,
  set_b
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rand_id, * FROM BWWM
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  set_a
INNER JOIN
  set_b
    ON set_a.rand_id = set_b.rand_id
```

You don't actually need to randomise the order of both sets.  If one is random, the pairing is random.  In which case one set can be ordered by the primary key of your table *(for the fastest way to generate a sequential id)*.

Comment: This also works, and gives me a longer list of vehicles. Helped me understand the importance of assigning subqueries with variables! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by showing my test data:

```
create table BWMM
(
    makemodel   char(1)
)
insert into BWMM(makemodel)
select 'A' union
select 'B' union
select 'C' union
select 'D' union
select 'E'
```

The following should give you a single row of the randomly selected top n rows (in this case n=5) of data in unique columns:

```
;with cte as (
    select *,
        [row] = row_number() over(order by newID())
    from BWMM
)
select min(case when row=1 then makemodel else null end),
    min(case when row=2 then makemodel else null end),
    min(case when row=3 then makemodel else null end),
    min(case when row=4 then makemodel else null end),
    min(case when row=5 then makemodel else null end)
from cte
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!! I don't have enough rep to upvote you, I would 1000 times over though.

Comment: And so for 100 rows of input data you need 100 case statements?  Why are you pivotting the data?  I think I must have missed something obvious!

Comment: @Dems, the OP modified the question... originally it looked like he was interested in pivoting rows to random columns...